# JSOUP select <div> with specific ID

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm making a small Android application for a class where I find cancer-related events from the American Cancer Society's website.  I've been using JSoup to get basic information about the events, and to get specific information from the website I've tried to use the select() method.  However, the current method that I'm using grabs way more HTML nodes than I would like and I couldn't figure out why.  The table that I'm trying to grab looks like this:

EDIT: I realized that the  where id = "pnlResults" does not end at that table, it ends after about 3 more tables, all with information that I would like to grab.  Here is the table again

```
    <div id="pnlResults">

        <h2><span id="lblEventName">American Cancer Society 44th Annual Walter Hagen Golf Tournament</span></h2>
        <!-- General Information Box -->
        <div class="text-box boxed wide">
            <h3 class="head" style="width:97%;">
                General Information
            </h3>
            <div class="content">


                <p>
                    <label>Event Times:</label><span id="lblStartDate">Monday, July 30, 2012</span><span id="lblEndDate"></span><br />
                    <label>&nbsp;</label><span id="lblStartTime">10:00 AM</span> - <span id="lblEndTime">9:00 PM</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Time Zone:</label><span id="lblTimeZone">Eastern</span>

                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Description:</label><span id="lblDesc" class="fieldData long">The American Cancer Society Walter Hagen Golf Tournament highlights the Society’s role in supporting research and patient care here in Rochester. Funds raised through this event help us make a difference in patents’ lives every day though programs including Road to Recovery and Patient Navigation as well as support grants to our research institutions.  144 golfers will play a round of golf and then enjoy cocktails, dinner, and silent auction following the tournament. </span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Agenda:</label><span id="lblAgenda" class="fieldData long">10:00am - Check-in, 11:00am - Lunch, 12:15pm - Shot gun start, 6:00 - Cocktails and silent auction, 7:00pm Dinner and program</span>
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="pnlStandardDisplay">


        <!-- Event Location Box -->
        <div class="text-box boxed wide line">
            <h3 class="head" style="width:97%;">
                Event Location
            </h3>
            <div class="content" style="display:inline-block; width:97%;">


                <div >
                    <div id="mapOutsideContainer" class="resource-map">
                       <div id="map_canvas" class="resource-map" ></div>
                    </div> 
                    <script  type="text/javascript">
                        var mapDataPoints = [{ "lat":43.1075545,"lng":-77.5164518, "title":"Golf Event","content":"<b>American Cancer Society 44th Annual Walter Hagen Golf Tournament<\/b><br/><\/br>4045 East Avenue<br /><br/>Rochester, New York  14618<br /><br />Phone: <br />Fax: "} ];
                        buildMap(mapDataPoints, -5);
                    </script>
                </div>

                <h4><span id="lblLocationName">Irondequoit Country Club</span></h4>
                <p>

                    <label>Address:</label><span id="lblAddress" class="fieldData" style="width:150px;">4045 East Avenue<br />Rochester, New York 14618</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label nowrap="nowrap">Handicap Accessible:</label><span id="lblHandicapAccesible">Yes</span>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Primary Contact Box -->
        <div class ="line" >
        <div id="eventPrimaryContact_divContact" class="text-box boxed wide">
                    <h3 class="head" style="width:97%;">
                        Primary Contact
                    </h3>
                    <div class="content">

                        <p>

                            <label>Contact:</label><span id="eventPrimaryContact_lblContact">Katerina Kormas (<a href="mailto:katerina.kormas@cancer.org?subject=American Cancer Society 44th Annual Walter Hagen Golf Tournament">Contact ACS for Details</a>)</span>

                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Contact Type:</label><span id="eventPrimaryContact_lblContactType">ACS Staff</span>
                        </p>
                        <p>

                            <label>Phone:</label><span id="eventPrimaryContact_lblContactPhone">(585) 288-1950</span>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Additional Information:</label><span id="eventPrimaryContact_lblContactAddlInfo" class="fieldData long">Direct line is 585-224-4919 or cell 585-645-8912</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Registration Information Box -->

        <div class="text-box boxed wide line">
            <h3 class="head" style="width:97%;">
                Registration Information
            </h3>
            <div class="content">

                <p>
                    <label nowrap="nowrap">Registration Required?: </label><span id="lblRegRequired">Yes</span>

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>       

        <!-- Event Cost Box -->
        <div class ="line" >
        <div id="eventCost_divCost" class="text-box boxed wide">
                    <h3 class="head" style="width:97%;">
                        Event Cost
                    </h3>
                    <div class="content">

                        <p>
                            <label>Cost/Registration Fee: </label><span id="eventCost_lblCostRegFee" class="fieldData long">$350 per golfer</span>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Payment Type: </label><span id="eventCost_lblPaymentTypes" class="fieldData">Cash, Check, American Express, Mastercard, Visa, Discover</span>
                        </p>
                        <p>

                            <label>Check Payable To: </label><span id="eventCost_lblCheckPayable" class="fieldData">American Cancer Society</span>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Memo Line: </label><span id="eventCost_lblCheckMemo" class="fieldData">American Cancer Society 44th Annual Walter Hagen Golf Tourna</span>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Mail Check To:</label><span id="eventCost_lblCheckMailTo" class="fieldData">American Cancer Society<br />1120 South Goodman St<br />Rochester, New York 14620</span>

                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Tax Deduction Information Box -->
        <div class="line">

                <div class="text-box boxed wide">
                    <h3 class="head" style="width:97%;">
                        Tax Deduction Information
                    </h3>

                    <div class="content">
                        <p>
                            $210  per golfer is tax deductible
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>  

        </div>



</div> <!-- end standard display -->
         <!-- end daffodil display -->
```

EDIT: Given these new tables, I would like to extract the General Information, and Event location. How would I go about doing that? Maybe using the subset of select I just got to select again Where the headers are what I want?

The code where I'm using the select() is shown below.  As I said before, I tried to use

```
select("div[id=pnlResults]);
```

but the returned data is much more than just the div where the id is pnlResults.

```
public ArrayList<Event> results()
{
    ArrayList<Event> results = new ArrayList<Event>();
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(page);
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href*=event-details]");

    for(Element e: links)
    {
        String title = e.text();
        String link = "http://www.cancer.org/involved/participate/app/"+e.attr("href");
        try{
            Document eventInfo = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
            Elements info = eventInfo.select("div[id*=pnlResults");


        }
        catch(MalformedURLException exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return results;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try:

```
 Elements info = eventInfo.select("div#pnlResults");
```

**Update for your update:**

Since you now have more data, and since the HTML itself isn't that great you'll just have to work through it to pick out your data. If the content you need all have `id` values then use the `id` attribute of those elements to get the text.

Comment: that worked but I didn't realize that the table didn't end at that last </div> that I had posted

Comment: @Tom: If C0deAttack's post helped you, please up-vote it. 1+ to C0deAttack because it sure helped me!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to get content of the div with id "pnlResults", JSoup provide method **getElementById**.

For example, if you want get that content and put it in string, you can do it like this:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(LINK_TO_WEBSITE).get();
String content = document.getElementById("pnlResults").outerHtml();
```

Then, you can put this content in Android's WebView, and it will work nice.

Hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class DivStuff {
   public static final String MY_PAGE = "http://www.cancer.org/Involved/Participate/app" +
        "/event-search.aspx?zip=28590&city=&state=&local-radius=20&textsrch=&startdate=" +
        "11%2F13%2F2011&enddate=&all=1";
   private static final String[] HEADINGS = {"Event", "Location", "City, State", "Date", "Distance"};
   private String page;


   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Document doc = Jsoup.connect(MY_PAGE).get();

      Elements links = doc.select("table");
      Elements links2 = links.select("tr");

      if (links2.size() < 2) {
         return;
      }

      for (int i = 1; i < links2.size(); i++) {
         Elements innerDetails = links2.get(i).select("td");
         if (innerDetails.size() != 5) {
            break;
         }
         for (int j = 0; j < HEADINGS.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(HEADINGS[j] + ": ");
            if (j == 0) {
               System.out.println(innerDetails.get(j).select("a").get(0).text());
            } else {
               System.out.println(innerDetails.get(j).text());
            }
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you, sir, are the man.  However, from those original results, when you go to the event description webpage, you can get the address, and other specifics that I would like to have.

Comment: @Tom: I don't understand you. Do you mean to say that your program is working now?

Comment: It's still a work in progress, but I have a good idea where to go based on your code. I should be able to add a few things to it and get what I want.