# how to get innerhtml using regex

Tags: java, regex

how to get innerhtml with nested tags using regex

Example:

```
<div class="def">
<ul>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="def">
<ul>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need only the first div content of this code
`"(?s)(<div\\sclass=\"def\">(.+)<\\/div>)"`
when ever i use this code i get both the div contents

How to get just the first one alone ?

Please help...

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: by using a good html parser

Comment: Help yourself and the world by stop using regex for html parsing.

Answer (score 7):

This is becuase of `.+` in your regex..Change it to `.+?`

But you should **NEVER** use REGEX for parsing html..

Use an [HTML PARSER](http://jsoup.org/) and here's how to [get div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114570/jsoup-select-div-with-specific-id)

---

Why use parser?

Consider your regex..There are infinite number of cases where you could break your code

- Your regex won't work if there are **nested** divs
- Some divs dont have an **ending tag**!(except XHTML)

To summarize don't ever ever ever ever ever ever use regex for parsing html

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza hmm..that one is great